# PHP-Error logging plesk

Tags: plesk, error-logging

I would like to know, how to enable enable PHP error-logging in Plesk 11.

I found PHP-Settings for my domain, but for error-reporting it says "standard". Which seems to me, like it doesn't create a log file at all.

What I want to achieve:
- log errors to file, but don't put them out to users.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP error logging seems can be found here:

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/statistics/logs/error_log
```

For grabbing only PHP errors:

```
grep PHP /var/www/vhosts/example.org/statistics/logs/error_log | less
```

Info: Only tested for Plesk 11

Comment: `/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/logs/error_log` for me on plesk 11.5.30. I will note that the default did seem to be to log. (You might add that to your answer, considering the original question.)